# Obter dados de item em ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto da faculdade que consiste em uma agenda que funciona com banco de dados SQLite. Pode parecer trivial, mas a forma como estou procedendo torna as coisas um pouco mais complexas.

Quero que, ao clicar em um item de lista, o usuário seja direcionado para outra activity com um formulário, cujos campos já estarão carregados com os dados mostrados na ListView clicada. Eu já tentei fazer pegando a posição do item e utilizando como ID a ser retornado, mas eu teria de fazer duas operações, uma pra ler no banco de dados e uma pra atualizar. Se houver uma forma de pegar os dados do item da listview e enviar pra outra activity diretamente após o clique, eu faria apenas uma ação, que seria a de update. Sendo assim, como posso fazer isto que planejo?

Comment: Seria bom adicionar o que você já fez. Assim facilita na construção da resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim.
Na sua activity você coloca:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object objetoComDados = adaptador.getItem(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityQueRecebeOsDados.class);
                    intent.putExtra("dados",objetoComDados);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

E no seu adaptador você coloca assim:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter{
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listaDeObjetos.get(position);
    }
}
```

E para pegar os dados na activity você faz assim:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if( getIntent().hasExtra("dados");){              
       Object objectoComDados  = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dados");
```

}

Lembrando que a classe do 'objetoComDados' tem que implementar a interface 'Serializable'.